# How to fix Unchecked runtime.lastError: Failed to capture tab: image readback failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a color picker extension when you click on `pick color` button, I'ts take a screenshot of the active tab, everything work until I press go back button on the browser and then it throw me the exception Unchecked runtime.lastError: Failed to capture tab: image readback failed here is my code :

```
 chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowType : "normal", currentWindow: true} , function(tabs) {
        console.log("on click", tabs[0])
        const windowId = tabs[0].windowId;
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
                windowId, {
                    "format":"jpeg",
                    "quality": 100,
                },
            ).then(dataUrl => {
                createCanvas(dataUrl);
            }).catch(e => console.log("error capture tab", e))
    });
```

can someone please explain me why this exception thrown and what does it mean

Comment: did you solve this issue? We have the same problem in our extension.

Comment: I remembered I didn't solve this it's was happening to me only on stack overflow i don't have any idea why this is happening  but i checked another extensions that do the same thing it's happened at all of them so we decide to leave it like this if you have an answer for this i will love to hear the solution @pawelbylina

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this error and here's how I solved it.

I hope that helps.

`webextension-polyfill`: A lightweight polyfill library for Promise-based WebExtension APIs in Chrome.

https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

```json
{
   ...
   "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

```js
const id = xxxxxxx // a tab, what you want capture.

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (tabId === id && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
        console.log("onUpdated", tabId, changeInfo, tab);
        await browser.tabs.update(tabId, {
            active: true
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            browser.tabs
                .captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId)
                .then((imageData) => {
                    console.log("captureVisibleTab", imageData);
                    if (imageData) {
                        console.log("data: ", imageData);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("captureVisibleTab error: ", error);
                });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```